# Code snippet doesnot compile under C++17, namespace issue?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace Cactus
{
    namespace Json
    {
        class Value
        {
        public:
            Value(){}

        };

    }

    typedef std::vector< int >      vectorInt;

    inline Cactus::Json::Value& operator << (Cactus::Json::Value& os, const vectorInt& v)
    {
        return os;
    }
    inline Cactus::Json::Value& operator >> (Cactus::Json::Value& is, vectorInt& v)
    {
        return is;
    }
}

namespace App
//namespace Cactus
{

    void f()
    {
        Cactus::vectorInt ints;
        Cactus::Json::Value val;

        val << ints;
    }
}

int main()
{
    App::f();
}
```

meets error,

```
main.cpp: In function 'void App::f()':
main.cpp:38:13: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'Cactus::Json::Value' and 'Cactus::vectorInt' {aka 'std::vector<int>'})
   38 |         val << ints;
      |         ~~~ ^~ ~~~~
      |         |      |
      |         |      Cactus::vectorInt {aka std::vector<int>}
      |         Cactus::Json::Value
```

But if use "namespace Cactus", it will compile. But I have to use "namespace App", any suggestions?

Updated: Problem is solved.
Move the two operators to global namespace works.
Or add using Cactus works too.

Comment: Put the operators into namespace Json

Comment: you need to declare the operators in the same namespace as the types: https://godbolt.org/z/7aoTav, see [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) for why

Comment: Alternatively, you could explicitly bring the `operator<<` into scope.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't think the dupe target is right. OP could solve their problem without modifying `Cactus` at all.

Comment: There's no need to modify `Cactus`? Just need to move inside the `Json` namespace same as in the dupe?

Comment: That would work, but it's not necessary. Why modify `Cactus` or `Json` in any way, if not needed?

Comment: @cigien A reason for modifying `Cactus` and `Json` is that you would have one set of changes that cover all uses of this particular operator overload. This could be more convenient than adding a `using` line in each scope that wants to use the overload.

Comment: @JaMiT True, that's probably the better approach, I edited my answer too. Perhaps I jumped the gun trying to solve the exact problem. There must be a dupe somewhere showing both approaches though.

Comment: To see an interesting aspect of argument-dependent lookup, change the line `typedef std::vector< int > vectorInt;` to `class vectorInt {};`. The error goes away! *(This is presented as an experiment for greater understanding, not a solution. It might also be an aspect not covered by otherwise-potential duplicates.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those operator overloads must be in the scope where your `f` function is. When you function `f` is in `Cactus` namespace, those operator overloads are in scope. But when it is under namespace `App` , those go out of scope. So either put those operator overloads in global namespace, or put operator overloads in same namespace as class `Value` , or put all functions using that operator in same namespace. Another way is to use `using` statements inside functions using them to import them to global scope for that function.

Comment: The overloads do not have to be in the scope where `f` is. That is one option, but another option is to put them in the scope where `Value` is defined. (In other words, the answer is mostly good, but the decision to use the word "must" is not good.)

Answer (score 3):

It is known as `ADL`. At least, in your example, function `Cactus::Json::Value& operator << (Cactus::Json::Value& os, const vectorInt& v)` can't be found in the associated classes or namespaces of the type of the argument `val`. Because the `ADL` should be governed by the following rules:

> For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a set of zero or more associated classes to be considered. The sets of namespaces and classes are determined entirely by the types of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template argument). **Typedef names and using-declarations used to specify the types do not contribute to this set.** The sets of namespaces and classes are determined in the following way:
>
> > If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. **Its associated namespaces are the innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes.** [...]

> If an associated namespace is an inline namespace, its enclosing namespace is also included in the set. If an associated namespace directly contains inline namespaces, those inline namespaces are also included in the set.

So, the innermost enclosing namespace of class `Value` is  `Json`. In the scope of `Value`, there is no such an available function in it and similarly for namespace `Json`, hence you meet that error.

---

How to resolve that?

1. Move all functions you provided to namespace `Json`.
2. Modify `namespace Json` to `inline namespace Json`.

Take one of them, then that will be fine.